# Flutter Layout suggestion

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and aim a little bit confused on how to create a certain layout
I am attaching an image of a layout how i need it:

[image: te]

I tried the Expanded widget but it does give the correct height especially for the the widgets at the bottom 
can anyone help or suggest what should I do? 
I just need what container to use the code could be just text or containers

how to put the height of each widget to match the screen

Comment: Sorry but this will be closed. Please add the code you have right now, even if it's not returning the desired output so that we can help.

Comment: better if u read what i have listed before commenting and waiting your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use Widgets like ListView, Column with SingleChildScrollView( Nest Column with SingleChildScrollView). They provide you with the ability to add widgets with a scrolling effect

Example -

```
return ListView(
   children: <Widget>[
       Container(
          child:Text("Text 1"),
       ),
       AnyVideoPlayingWidget(),
       CarouselWidget(),
   ],
);
```

For Carousel Slider you can look into this package ->
[Carousel Slider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

For Playing videos you can try this package -> [Chewie Video Player Package](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie)

For more info on basic layouts, read this article on the official website -> [Layouts in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout)

Comment: how to put the height of each widget to match the screen

Comment: double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width